# ANY way to consolidate this code?

Tags: php, validation, forms, storage, consolidation

I am building a PHP registration form which takes the following fields for up to 20 athletes:

> First Name Middle Initial Last Name
>   Federation Number Address City State
>   Zip DOB SSN Phone Email

I am only through 7 of the fields for each fighter and my php file is very large (over 40kb). Is there ANY way to consolidate this code at all? I am also having to validate the information on each field (as I said - 20 athletes x 12 fields = 240 validations on a single page).

If I can send any further code let me know!

```
<form id="Form"  action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return Enroll_Form_Validator(this)">
<p class="title">Your Fighters' Information</p>
<p>Please complete the following fields with your <span style="color:red;"> Fighters' Information</span> to continue your enrollment.</p>
<br />

<?php
    // if $errors is not empty, the form must have failed one or more validation 
    // tests. Loop through each and display them on the page for the user
    if (!empty($errors))
    {
      echo "<div class='error'>Please fix the following errors:\n<ul>";
      foreach ($errors as $error)
        echo "<li>$error</li>\n";

      echo "</ul></div>"; 
    }    
?>

<?php if ($_SESSION['Num_Fighters'] > "0") { ?>
    <table class="demoTable">
    <tr>
      <td>First Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1FirstName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1FirstName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Middle Initial: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1MI" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1MI']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1LastName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1LastName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Federation No: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1FedNum" maxlength="10" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1FedNum']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SSN: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1SSN1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1SSN1']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F1SSN2" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1SSN2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F1SSN3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1SSN3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
        <td>
        <select name="F1DOB1">
            <option value="">Month</option> 
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F1DOB1"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>            
        </select> / 
        <select name="F1DOB2">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F1DOB2"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select> / 
        <select name="F1DOB3">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F1DOB3"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1Address" value="<?php echo $fields['F1Address']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1City" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1City']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State: </td>
        <td><select name="F1State"><option value="">Choose a State</option><?php showOptionsDrop($states_arr, null, true); ?></select></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip Code: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1Zip" size="6" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1Zip']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Telephone No: </td>
        <td>( <input type="text" name="F1Phone1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1Phone1']; ?>" /> ) 
        <input type="text" name="F1Phone2" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1Phone2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F1Phone3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F1Phone3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F1Email" value="<?php echo $fields['F1Email']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>
<?php } ?>
<br />
<?php if ($_SESSION['Num_Fighters'] > "1") { ?>   
    <table class="demoTable">
    <tr>
      <td>First Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2FirstName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2FirstName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Middle Initial: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2MI" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2MI']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2LastName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2LastName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Federation No: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2FedNum" maxlength="10" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2FedNum']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SSN: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2SSN1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2SSN1']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F2SSN2" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2SSN2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F2SSN3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2SSN3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
        <td>
        <select name="F2DOB1">
            <option value="">Month</option> 
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F2DOB1"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>            
        </select> / 
        <select name="F2DOB2">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F2DOB2"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select> / 
        <select name="F2DOB3">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F2DOB3"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2Address" value="<?php echo $fields['F2Address']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2City" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2City']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State: </td>
        <td><select name="F2State"><option value="">Choose a State</option><?php showOptionsDrop($states_arr, null, true); ?></select></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip Code: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2Zip" size="6" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2Zip']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Telephone No: </td>
        <td>( <input type="text" name="F2Phone1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2Phone1']; ?>" /> ) 
        <input type="text" name="F2Phone2" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2Phone2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F2Phone3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F2Phone3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F2Email" value="<?php echo $fields['F2Email']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>
<?php } ?>
<br />
<?php if ($_SESSION['Num_Fighters'] > "2") { ?>   
    <table class="demoTable">
    <tr>
      <td>First Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3FirstName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3FirstName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Middle Initial: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3MI" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3MI']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3LastName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3LastName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Federation No: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3FedNum" maxlength="10" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3FedNum']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SSN: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3SSN1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3SSN1']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F3SSN2" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3SSN2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F3SSN3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3SSN3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
        <td>
        <select name="F3DOB1">
            <option value="">Month</option> 
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F3DOB1"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>            
        </select> / 
        <select name="F3DOB2">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F3DOB2"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select> / 
        <select name="F3DOB3">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F3DOB3"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3Address" value="<?php echo $fields['F3Address']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3City" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3City']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State: </td>
        <td><select name="F3State"><option value="">Choose a State</option><?php showOptionsDrop($states_arr, null, true); ?></select></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip Code: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3Zip" size="6" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3Zip']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Telephone No: </td>
        <td>( <input type="text" name="F3Phone1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3Phone1']; ?>" /> ) 
        <input type="text" name="F3Phone2" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3Phone2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F3Phone3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F3Phone3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F3Email" value="<?php echo $fields['F3Email']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>
<?php } ?>
<br />
<?php if ($_SESSION['Num_Fighters'] > "3") { ?>   
    <table class="demoTable">
    <tr>
      <td>First Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4FirstName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4FirstName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Middle Initial: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4MI" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4MI']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4LastName" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4LastName']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Federation No: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4FedNum" maxlength="10" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4FedNum']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SSN: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4SSN1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4SSN1']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F4SSN2" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4SSN2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F4SSN3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4SSN3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
        <td>
        <select name="F4DOB1">
            <option value="">Month</option> 
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F4DOB1"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>            
        </select> / 
        <select name="F4DOB2">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F4DOB2"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select> / 
        <select name="F4DOB3">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
          {
            echo "<option value='$i'";
            if ($fields["F4DOB3"] == $i)
              echo " selected";
            echo ">$i</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4Address" value="<?php echo $fields['F4Address']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4City" onkeyup="if(!this.value.match(/^([a-z]+\s?)*$/i))this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4City']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State: </td>
        <td><select name="F4State"><option value="">Choose a State</option><?php showOptionsDrop($states_arr, null, true); ?></select></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zip Code: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4Zip" size="6" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4Zip']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Telephone No: </td>
        <td>( <input type="text" name="F4Phone1" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4Phone1']; ?>" /> ) 
        <input type="text" name="F4Phone2" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4Phone2']; ?>" /> - 
        <input type="text" name="F4Phone3" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '')" value="<?php echo $fields['F4Phone3']; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="F4Email" value="<?php echo $fields['F4Email']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>
<?php } ?>
<div align="right"><input class="enrbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" /></div>
</form>
```

This only goes through 4 athletes and I need it to capture 20. Any ideas? I am forced to keep all 200+ elements in SESSION assuming somebody enrolls 20 athletes.

Comment: I've not read the code very carefully, but couldn't you make it a function you would call 1, 2, 3... 20 times ?

Comment: @Shelldon - I suppose that is what I'm looking for but not sure how to do it really. I need the information entered to be unique (i.e. it cant all be stored as FirstName; it must be placed as F1FirstName, F2FirstName where F1 and F2 are the athlete identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Throw this code away](http://codebetter.com/blogs/eric.wise/archive/2006/06/25/146821.aspx).
2. [Seperate your html files from your php code.](http://www.google.com/search?q=seperate+html+from+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)
3. Use a [MVC pattern](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) if you
   are ambitious.
4. Use a [validation
   class.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html)
5. Profit!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have every page on the site coded as PHP (use of include files and such). How exactly do you recommend separating the two when using this form? I am diong the validation on the same page (because I want to return errors on the same page and keep information entered on the same page as well).

I am already using a validation class which i require_once() at the top of the page based on the 'rules' I define at the top of the page itself.

Comment: Read through the links I sent you. In particular, check out the Zend form link Jeremy talks about below. You will be amazed how your 40kb form turns into one that is 2kb, is much prettier and WAY easier to maintain. Write the code in the Zend quick start, it is just copy and paste, but it will open your eyes to how well written php should look. It will seem harder at first, but trust me, when you get it, it'll be the biggest ahah! moment since you learned to code. Really.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice Byron. I will certainly get to it this week. In the meantime I may have to live with my garbage code since we are taking a live run-through for a project we are building (this one) tomorrow. The one thing I have been unable to find in other languages that I'm running into now is the ability to label the input of fields and validate them dynamically. I need to store ALL my information collected but never intend to use it for anything so querying the DB is pointless. We are simply capturing and passing a long so the main importance to me is size and speed - not separating

Comment: @JM4 - Zend_Validate along with Zend_Form will do exactly what you want. Run through the tutorial as it is beyond the scope of this comment box. It is nice to know you want to improve your code. Alot of folks don't take enough pride in their work to improve it. Sounds like we have the beginnings of an awesome programmer here! Don't forget to give bakc to the SO community. Good luck.

Comment: I am sticking with it and going to give this a fair shot but if using Zend is ANYTHING like the process to get it running and the HORRIBLE guides they provide then I'm not sure I will find any use in this. Getting it put together on my local machine has been a pain in the ass, let alone the hours of work I'm sure I'll have to put it just to get it configured on our hosted server (which we don't manage). I have never in my life seen an 'install' process so complicated for any programming language/framework.

Answer (score 2):

Forms can be a real pain.  I'm with Byron, but I'd like to further point out that you don't have to use Zend's MVC components to use [Zend Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html).  I've gotten a lot of mileage out plugging Zend Form into some of my non-mvc projects.

Comment: @Jeremy - Thanks for the follow up on Byron's note. I am completely unfamiliar with Zend Form (and Zend Framework in general for that matter). What are the advantages of using it over traditional html/php form building?

Comment: @Jeremy +1 The best part about Zend is its modularity, You can use any part you want without using the whole framework.

Comment: @JM4 - The big benefit of using a code library over "rolling your own" is that almost everything you want or need to do has been done already, no need to do it yourself.  Specific to Zend Form, input validation, filtering, html code generation and error message generation and handling are all handled for you, and it's all reusable.

Comment: Thanks to you both - I am a very, very rookie "programmer" so trying to learn how to fly the plane while already in the air. I know this isn't the normal way things should be done but working with some friends on a start-up takes you that way!

Comment: @JM4 - Trial by fire is how I learned.  It can be one of the best ways. I'm with Byron - "Sounds like we have the beginnings of an awesome programmer here!"

Comment: Holy Hell - I am hours in and still can't even figure out how to configure the D*mn software to run and utilize. The 'tutorial' files are extremely difficult to follow as they don't even tell you where to insert the example code they are running. I installed PHP, MySQL and Apache on my local machine using XAMPP; compared to that process this is brain surgery.

In order to get this installed on our webserver (which is hosted elsewhere of course) does this mean I need to have them modify the php.ini files and all this other configuration as well?

Comment: @JM4 - Ouch. Sorry to hear that. Maybe it's time to head over to Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/)?  Server config is not my bag.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Didn't even know that site existed.